# Can't copy certain gvim text, eg :version or error messages

Tags: vim, gvim, clipboard

Generally, my copy/paste works just fine in vim.

However, when I type :version, my mouse pointer becomes a symbol like:

[image: no, not allowed]

While I can select text, I can't copy it to the clipboard.

Exactly the same behaviour with error output.

How do I disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that message output mode, copying with the mouse indeed isn't possible. Only a few paging commands are available there. So, that "feature" doesn't exist yet.

There are several ways to obtain the output. The most generic is via `:redir`, e.g. into the *unnamed register*:

```
:redir @"
:version
:redir END
:put
```

For a single (last) error message, you can also directly access this via `v:errmsg`:

```
:put =v:errmsg
```

In the terminal, you could also disable Vim's mouse integration via `:set mouse=`, and then use the terminal's mouse drag to copy the (visible) text.

Comment: You can make a single command in your vim rc: `command! PutMessages redir @" | messages | redir END | put`

Comment: This doesn't seem to function in NeoVim/VimR, unless I misunderstand how it's supposed to be used? When invoking `:PutMessages`, the `:messages` are still just printed in red, not copied. (However, `:let @+=v:errmsg works for me; so I know my clipboard support is functioning!)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `'clipboard'` option to `autoselect` Vim will automatically attempt to become the owner of the system's copy buffer.  This will let you copy text in the situations you describe.

Comment: does not work with MacVim or neovim